# how to assign 'selected' to html drop down list asp.net vb

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

im fairly new to the world of .net net programming. I am stuck with the following:
I have a dynamic dropdown list:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim ConnectString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("eAppDBConnectionString").ToString
        Dim QueryString As String = "SELECT [AcademicYearID],[Description] FROM Ref_AcademicYear"

        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectString)
        Dim myCommand As New SqlDataAdapter(QueryString, myConnection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        myCommand.Fill(ds, "AcademicYear")

        Select1.DataSource = ds
        Select1.DataTextField = "AcademicYearID"
        Select1.DataValueField = "Description"
        Select1.SelectedIndex = 4
        Select1.DataBind()
    End If
```

The list populates ok with values of '12/13, 13/14, 14/15, 15/16, 16/17'etc. So I wanted the default selected item to be '15/16' but i cannot seem to work that out. I have Select1.SelectedIndex = 4 but that only takes the index value.

please help. Thanks

Comment: try Select1.SelectedValue = 4

Answer (score 0):

Put this in after 
  Select1.DataBind()

```
   For Each item In Select1.Items
        If item.value = "15/16" Then
            item.selected = True
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

that didnt work but i put the the following line after the databind() and it worked:

Select1.Items.FindByValue("15/16").Selected = True